# Read a .text file and place the data in an 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I make this work? I have a txt file where I have data I want to store like this in an 2d array

```
1.
title: 
cont: 
path:

2.
title: 
cont: 
path:

3.
title: 
cont: 
path:
```

It's just printing `null` on every array index?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Filip\\Desktop\\file.txt"));
            String file;
            while ((file = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println("DEBUG: " + file);
                //System.out.println("DEBUG: " + file.split(";"));

                String[] anArray;

                anArray = file.split(";");
                //for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println(anArray[i]);
                //}

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Test");

                String[][] filmer = new String[anArray.length / 3][20];

                for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length / 3; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        System.out.println(filmer[i][j]);

                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error, file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `file.split(";");` shouldn't you use `:` as delimiter instead of `;` ?